# Link Server Between PostgreSQL and SQL Server got inconsistent data

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have a problem with a linked server between SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition to PostgreSQL. Some tables I can select but when I want to access to specific table I get an error.

> Msg 7356, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "b2c" supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column "tsv_reference" (compile-time ordinal 45) of object ""astraotoshop_b2"."product"."products"" was reported to have a "DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISLONG" of 128 at compile time and 0 at run time.

Can someone tell me where the error is?

Thanks

Comment: So what's the true type of that column?

Comment: It is coming as the length of the column:tsv_reference , is very long. you can CAST the column to proper length. read more: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/the-ole-db-provider-quot-msdasql-quot-for-linked-server-quot/ba-p/318618 & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/features/using-large-value-types?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 3):

I found this answer here
I finally figured out the issue.

Just in case anyone else is having this problem, a workaround is to go to Start > Search ODBC Data Source Administrator > System DNS > Configure

Once the pop up window opens, under Options go to Datasource.

Then untick Bools as Char, apply and save.

Comment: Thank you this fixed my issue. This also needs to be done separately for each dsn and is not a global setting.